# R Error: inherits(x, c("DocumentTermMatrix", "TermDocumentMatrix")) is not TRUE

Tags: r, nlp, tm, text-analysis

I am creating a Document Term Matrix with the following code. I have no problem creating the matrix, but when I try to Remove Sparse Terms or find Frequent Terms, I get an error.

```
text<- c("Since I love to travel, this is what I rely on every time.", 
         "I got this card for the no international transaction fee", 
         "I got this card mainly for the flight perks",
         "Very good card, easy application process",
         "The customer service is outstanding!") 

library(tm)
corpus<- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)

dtm<- as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(corpus))
```

Here is the result:

```
Docs    application card    customer    easy    every ... etc.
1       0           0       0           1       0
2       0           1       0           0       1
3       0           1       0           0       0
4       1           1       0           0       0
5       0           0       1           0       0
```

Here is where I get the error using either **removeSparseTerms** or **findFreqTerms**

```
sparse<- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.80)
freq<- findFreqTerms(dtm, 2)
```

Result

```
Error: inherits(x, c("DocumentTermMatrix", "TermDocumentMatrix")) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[removeSparseTerms](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tm/versions/0.7-1/topics/removeSparseTerms) and [findFreqTerms](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tm/versions/0.7-1/topics/findFreqTerms) are expecting a *DocumentTermMatrix* or a *TermDocumentMatrix* object not a matrix.

Create the DocumentTermMatrix without converting to a matrix and you won't get the error.

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
sparse <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.80)
freq <- findFreqTerms(dtm, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.. but how do I think convert it back to a matrix format? I tried taking sparse and freq like as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(sparse)) and that didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out.. I just did as.matrix(sparse) and that worked. Thanks again!